# splitting a list into lists

Tags: python, list

If I have obtained the following list as an output from a csv file:

```
[g1,g2,g3] [g2,g3,g4] [g3,g4,g5]
```

Via this code:

```
def KnockOut(cmod):
    f = open('csv.txt','r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        stripped_line = line.rstrip()
        genelist = stripped_line.split(',')
```

Now it seems whenever I iterate over `genelist`, I always iterate over all the 3 lists. My goal is to iterate over each list independently (and perform a function on all the 3 genes contained in the list). How can I split? this list into separate lists?

Cheers,
Jordy

Comment: Can you share your snippet for iterating this list and explain how it's output is not what you're expecting?

Comment: I need to perfrom a function on the first list [g1,g2,g3] and only then perform the function on the 2th list and only then on the third list etc. When I for loop over this list it iterates over all the lists. I want to make it seperate lists

Answer (score 1):

You can access each element using its index (starting from 0):

```
for gene in genelist:
    g1 = gene[0]
    g2 = gene[1]
    g3 = gene[2]
    ...do something with g1, g2 and g3...
```

Comment: Alright, but how do I now perform a function on the items of the first list (g1,g2,g3)? I need to shut down those genes as one data set. Only then I want to move on to the next three genes

Comment: @Cheeseburgler If there will always be 3 genes in each list, see my updated answer.